# Nested / alternating apps with Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'd like to have a kivy app function as a launcher for other kivy apps, depending on input. The way I implemented it below is obviously not working (because the `kv` file gets reloaded and its styles reapplied, thus adding more and more buttons), and there also seems to be some recursion as the trace suggests when I hit `Esc` to exit.

I do get the warning that `app1.kv` is loaded multiple times, however, in the documentation for `App.load_kv()` it says

> This method is invoked the first time the app is being run if no
>           widget tree has been constructed before for this app.

This implies to me that it should be possible to `run()` an app multiple times?

Here is my code:

**main.py**

```
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.logger import Logger
from kivy.lang import Builder

class OutsideApp(App):
    current_app = ObjectProperty(None)

    def build(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 3)
        return Widget()

    def update(self, dt):
        if isinstance(self.current_app, App):
            self.current_app.stop()
        if isinstance(self.current_app, App1):
            self.current_app = App2()
        else:
            self.current_app = App1()
        self.current_app.run()

class App1(App):
    pass
class App2(App):
    def build(self):
        gl = Builder.load_string("<SequencesGame@GridLayout>:\n cols: 2\n   Button:\n       text: \"hello 2\"\nSequencesGame:")
        return gl

if __name__ == '__main__':
    oa = OutsideApp()
    oa.run()
```

**app1.kv**

```
#:kivy 1.0.9
<SequencesGame@GridLayout>:
    cols: 2
    Button:
        text: "hello 111"
SequencesGame:
```

This seems to be an issue even if apps are not nested:

**main2.py**

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.logger import Logger
from kivy.lang import Builder

class App1(App):
    pass
class App2(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string("<SequencesGame@GridLayout>:\n   cols: 2\n   Button:\n       text: \"hello 2\"\nSequencesGame:")

current_app = None

def switch(*args):
    global current_app
    if isinstance(current_app, App):
        current_app.stop()
    if isinstance(current_app, App1):
        current_app = App2()
    else:
        current_app = App1()
    current_app.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Clock.schedule_interval(switch, 2)
    switch()
```

Comment: Can't you just have one app with multiple screens under screen manager, where each screen is ,,another app''?

Comment: I'd like to reuse existing apps. Also, things like config files seem to be nicely encapsulated on the app level.

Comment: Why not run the other apps in a subprocess instead?

Comment: @inclement Some data (in particular a network stack) would be shared (network messages are passed on from the outside in). Not sure how that would work with subprocesses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I followed @inclement's suggestion of using [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html). Here is a basic implementation (without communication through Pipes or Queues):

```
import sys
import multiprocessing
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import  Builder
from time import sleep#, localtime, time

def str_to_class(str):
    return reduce(getattr, str.split("."), sys.modules[__name__])

class App1(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string("BoxLayout:\n    Button:\n       text: \"hello 1\"")

class App2(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string("BoxLayout:\n    Button:\n       text: \"hello 2\"")


class Wrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, *kargs, **kwargs):
        super(Wrapper, self).__init__()
        self.running_app = None
        self.next_app = 'App1'

    def change_running_app(self, name='App1'):
        if self.running_app is not None:
            self.running_app.terminate()
        self.running_app = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.run_app, kwargs={'name':name})
        self.running_app.start()

    def run_app(self, name='App1'):
        app = str_to_class(name)()
        app.run()

    def swap(self):
        self.change_running_app(name=self.next_app)
        self.next_app = ['App1', 'App2']['App1' is self.next_app]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    counter = 0
    w = Wrapper()
    while True:
        counter += 1
        print "Started App instance {}".format(counter)
        w.swap()
        sleep(5)
```